# コマンドが終了したら音を鳴らしたい

Tags: bash, macos

ちょっと時間がかかるテストを回しながら開発しています。

```
$ python tests.py
```

テストが走っている間に次のテストを書いたりして時間の埋め合わせをしていますが、テストが終わったら前回変えたところを忘れないうちにすぐにテスト結果を見て対処したいです。

テストを実行するコマンドが終了したらビープ音か何かを鳴らせばいいかと思うのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか。

SSH越しのシェルでも動作するような方法がよいです。

おまけでコマンドの終了コードが 0 かそうでないかによって別の音 (ビープ音の数が違うのでもよい) にできればさらによいです。(補足: ただし、音は終了コードに関わらず常に鳴らしたい)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

一度ビープ音を鳴らしたいのであれば次のようにすればよいかと思います．

```
echo ^G
```

「^G」を入力するのには `C-v C-g` とタイプすればよいかと思います．
またはターミナルエミュレータの機能で出力があれば知らせるものもあるようです（[Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/)など）．

追記：

```
python test.py && echo ^G || (echo ^G; sleep 1; echo ^G)
```

ワンライナーがお好きなら，こう書くと正常終了時には一回，異常終了時には二回ビープが鳴るようにできます．単に成功失敗問わず鳴らしたいということならば

```
python test.py; echo ^G
```

です．

Answer (score 26):

Macの場合、sayコマンドが使用できます。自分は長いmakeビルドなどが終わったことを知らせるのに、sayコマンドを使っています

```
make && say Done
```

日本語の音声もつかえるので、日本語を喋らせても面白いです

```
make && say -v Otoya "終わったよ！"
```

Comment: これは初めて知りました。おもしろい

Answer (score 12):

テストが失敗した場合に音を鳴らすのであれば

```
python test.py || echo ^G
```

とします。`^G` は `CTRL-V` `CTRL-G` で入力します。

Comment: こちらの回答のようなワンライナー的な方が好きですが、テストが成功した時も失敗した時も音を鳴らしたいです

Answer (score 10):

`^G` を出力する例ばかりですが、移植性を考慮するなら tput を用いるべきです。

```
$ python test.py; tput bel
```

ベルを鳴らし続ける例:

```
$ python test.py; while :; do tput bel;sleep 1; done
```

`bel` など端末の機能名については Linux や *BSD ならオンラインマニュアル `terminfo`(5) の「Cap-name」あたりを見てください。

次のようなエイリアスを作っておくといいかもしれません。

```
$ alias alarm='e=$?; s=2; [ $e -ne 0 ] && { echo exit $e 1>&2; let s--; }; while :; do tput bel; sleep $s; done'
$ python test.py; alarm
```

この例のエイリアスコマンド `alarm` は、
直前のコマンドの終了コードが 0 の場合は2秒おきにベルを鳴らし、それ以外の場合は終了コードを表示して1秒おきにベルを鳴らします。

Answer (score 8):

音を鳴らす方法は他の方にお譲りして、私は別の角度からコメントします。コマンドを実行してしばらくしてから「時間かかるなぁ、これが終わった時に音を鳴らしたいなぁ」と後から思うことがよくあります。でも実行を中断して`; [音を鳴らすコマンド]`をつけて実行し直すのは、これまでせっかく計算してきたのに時間が無駄になってしまいます。そういう時は、私は`ps`を使っています。プロセスIDをpsで調べてからそのプロセスがある間はwhileループを回します。

```
python tests.py
# ...
# 時間がかかるなぁ...
# 中断するのもったいないなぁ...

# 別の端末を立ち上げて
ps # PIDを見る
while ps PID >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done; echo "done" # 音を鳴らしたり、出力ファイルを処理するなど
```

Answer (score 5):

シェクスクリプトで実行してからechoでビープ音文字を出力すればよいと思います。
実行結果は$?に入るのでそれを判定して音を鳴らす回数を変える事も出来ます。

```
#!/bin/sh
python tests.py

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo $'\a' #戻り値が０なら1回ビープ音
else
   echo $'\a\a\a' #それ以外では３回ビープ音
fi
```

Comment: @ento ワンラインで、というのであればこのスクリプトを改良して、ファイル名を引数から受け取るようにして、毎回スクリプト経由で実行したらどうでしょう。

Comment: `echo $'\a\a\a'` だと 1 回しかビープ音が鳴っていないように聞こえます (Mac OS X 上の bash)。別の環境だと使えるのでしょうか

Comment: @tmd45 コメントありがとうございます。それもありですね。ちなみにコメントをいただいた時点では、こちらの回答に私がコメントなどしていなかったため、通知が来ませんでした。質問の方にコメントいただければ質問の投稿者に通知が来ます。[通知のルールを訳してみました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/328/) ので参考になれば (長文注意)。

Comment: @ento こちらもmac上のbashなのですが３回鳴らせています。環境依存なのですかね。確実を期すのであれば上で書かれているようにsleepを挟むか複数行に分ければ良いと思います。

Comment: iTerm2を使ってるせいでした! 標準のターミナルアプリだといけました。

Answer (score 3):

DVDトレイを出し入れするejectコマンドを利用するのはどうでしょうか。

Raspberry Piでのやり方:

```sh
/usr/bin/eject -T
```

色々な利用例:
http://www.slideshare.net/Akkiesoft/20140927-ejecthandson

Comment: 気になったのでMacでのやり方を調べました: `/usr/bin/drutil tray [open|close]` だそうですね。ただしDVDトレイが付いてないマシンなので試せていません。なお、クリックしなくてもリンク先の内容がわかるよう概要を入れました。気にいらないところがあれば (お手数ですが) [edit]して上書きしてしまってください。

Answer (score 3):

システムで利用されている AIFF を使いリッチな音を再生するという方法もあります。

例

```
afplay /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/burn\ complete.aif
```

他にも `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds` にいくつか使えそうな音があります。

Answer (score 2):

同じように音を鳴らす設定にしていたことがありますが、トイレなどに立つと音を聞き逃すため、OS X の Notification Center を使うという方法にしたことがあります。

terminal-notifier というアプリケーションを入れ、
https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('/Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -message Done')
```

などを Python 側から呼べば、Mac の画面に通知が出ます (os-x のタグがついているので、Mac を想定します)。

もし `tests.py` の走っている Mac が他の Mac であれば、SSH を使うことで解決できます。通知を受け取りたい側の Mac に terminal-notifier をインストールし、`tests.py` の中から、スクリプト終了時に SSH を呼び出します。

```
import os
os.system("ssh YOUR_USER_NAME@YOUR_HOST /Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -message Done")
```

SSH を使う場合は、パスワード入力をしなくても良いように設定して下さい。

Comment: osascriptを使えば、素のMacでもNotifyを表示できます。
`echo 'display notification "Finished!" with title "Long operation"' | osascript`

Answer (score 2):

コマンドラインでいちいち`echo ^G`をつけるのは忘れてしまいますので、テストを走らせるシェルのプロンプトに`^G`を仕込むのはどうでしょう。あるいは`` `command` ``で何かコマンド (別の方が書いていらっしゃるように通知コマンドなど) をプロンプトに仕込んでおいて起動することも出来ます。